# Search a table without removing collapsed rows

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, list.js

so basically I have a table, and I'm using the search of list.js to search the table. I'm also highlighting the results with mark.js.
You can see a working version in the following link.

```
<tbody class="list context">
    <tr class="parent">
      <td class="name">Abraham</td>      
      <td class="city foo" data-foo="foo bar">Stockholm</td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">+</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child">
      <td class="collapse" colspan="3" id="collapseExample1">
        foo bar
      </td>
    </tr>
</tbody
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/KodeB/pen/yQxBMG?editors=1010)

Ok so the .child row is collapsible by clicking on the button. Now when i search for "Abraham", it removes the adjacent .child row.
Here is what needs to happen:
Show me every .parent row, if it matches the searchinput, but dont remove the .child, even if it doesnt match the input.

Show me every "parentrow", even if it doesnt match the input BUT the collapsed "childrow" does match.

Only remove "parent- and childrow" if neither of them matches the input.

I don't even know if my approach is the correct way to do this, it sure does feel hacky, so I'm open for other ideas aswell.

Greetings KDB

Comment: Tables should not be used for layout and you have a column count mismatch.  Also, the rows are siblings so how can you tell which is a parent and which is a child

Comment: Do you have to use List.js? If you are trying to do something less general it might be easier to implement it yourself

Comment: @Pete I am pretty sure he means parents have the class of 'city' and children are collapsible

Comment: @Katie.Sun hard to tell with such a small snippet of code - not all of us are able to click on the codepen links - that's why Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Comment: @Pete I edited the question and hope I could make it more clear now. The fact that it is hard for me to even describe the issue seems to be the main problem and indicates that my approach might be completely wrong.

Comment: @Katie.Sun no list.js is not required necessarily but I basically use the search, sort and filter functuality which already works without the collapsed rows.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know... at first glance it kind of seems like you might have to decide if it's more important to have the collapsible rows or to use List.js. I don't see anything in their docs for something like a conditional search